# C# Adding a Child form to my main form

Tags: c#, forms, menustrip, subforms

I need help  adding a new form where I will be asked to enter three numbers.

The thing is when I click on a menu strip on my main form, the new form will open, 
but the main one will not close, it must be active!

Comment: A bit of clarity on what you mean by "active" would help. Do you mean the user should be able to interact with both forms simultaneously?

Answer (score 7):

You can create a new form to take the three numbers and display it by instantiating the object and then displaying it from the _Click() event for the menu item.

If you want to be able to interact with both the main form and child form at the same time, use the Show() method.

```
MySubForm form = new MySubForm();
form.Show();
```

If you want the child form to be modal (the user must respond to it before going back) use the ShowDialog() method.

```
MySubForm form = new MySubForm();
form.ShowDialog();
```

For more details on working with ShowDialog [see the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

just create a object of form and show it 
see my code it can help you.
here `MyCustomForm` is a my form name you can use your own.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myForm = new MyCustomForm();
    myForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: also look into `myform.Show(this);` if you want your parent form disabled when the 'child' form is active.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to [activate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate.aspx) the second form you would like to show, or just set its Visible flag by calling the [Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd.aspx) methode or setting the [Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible.aspx) flag explicitely. evtl. you can hide the Main one if needed.